# udev rules attrs regular expression acceptation

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver, udev

I am trying to include an udev rule to create a customized /dev/ entry depending on usb device attribute. I have two different bar code scanner which have the word Bar code Scanner and Barcode Scanner into manufacturer attrs.

So I am wondering if can I make it work by add regex into ATTRS{manufacturer}, as following:

```
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="(([bB]ar\ ?[Cc]ode\ ?)([Ss]can\ ?(ner)?))"
```

or should I:

```
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="\([Bb]ar\(\s\?\)[Cc]ode\s\?[Ss]can\)"
```

The regex presented above will accept the following variations:

```
Bar code Scanner
barcode scanner
barcodescanner
Barcode Scanner
bar code scanner
bar code scan
Bar Code Scan
BarCode Scaner
barCode scanner
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [udev man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/udev):

> It supports the following pattern characters:
>
> - **"*"** Matches zero, one, or more characters.
> - **"?"** Matches any single character, but does not match zero characters.
> - **"[ ]"** Matches any single character specified within the brackets. For example, the pattern string "tty[SR]" would match either "ttyS" or
>     "ttyR". Ranges are also supported within this match with the '-'
>     character. For example, to match on the range of all digits, the
>     pattern [0-9] would be used. If the first character following the '['
>     is a '!', any character not enclosed is matched.
> - **"|"** Separates alternative patterns. For example, the pattern string "abc|x*" would match either "abc" or "x*".

In your case `"[Bb]ar[Cc]ode [Ss]can*|[Bb]ar [Cc]ode [Ss]can*"` should work.